# Google Apps Auth with edu.au domain

Tags: authentication, dns, accounts

I am trying to authentify a domain for google docs scope. This is the url:

https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest?next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.edu.au%2Fcomponents%2Fgoogle%2FretrieveToken.php&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Ffeeds%2F&session=1&secure=0&hd=default

So my domain is: www.mydomain.edu.au

But when makng the request Then i get this answer:

```
The page you have requested cannot be displayed. Another site was requesting access to your Google Account, but sent a malformed request. Please contact the site that you were trying to use when you received this message to inform them of the error. A detailed error message follows: 
 The site "http://edu.au" has not been registered.
```

So its identified as edu.au domain.

Is there a way around this?

Thanx

sample code for uploading document to google docs:

```
public static function uploadDocs($data = array())
{
    if (!self::checkInput($data)) return false;
    $data['url'] = Google::docsAPIUrl.'default/private/full'.self::getFolder($data['folderId']);
    //"?convert=false" 
    $headers = Google::getAuthToken();
    array_push($headers, Google::getGData());
    $contentHeaders = self::getInputHeaders($data);
    array_push($headers, 'Content-Length: '.$contentHeaders['length']);
    array_push($headers, 'Content-Type: '.$contentHeaders['type']);
    array_push($headers, 'Slug: '.Html::win2utf8($data['docTitle']));
    if ($data['inputMethod'] == 'File')
    {
        $data['input'] = ((fread(fopen($data['input'], 'rb'), filesize($data['input']))));
    }
    $curl = Google::curl($data['url'], null, $data['input'], $headers);
    if (Curl::checkCode($curl['code']))
    {
        return self::parseNewXML($curl['response']);
    }
    else
    {
        Google::$error = array('errorCode'=>$curl['code'],'errorString'=>$curl['response']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you offer more details about what you're actually trying to do here? End goal is...

Comment: My end goal is to generate PDF via google docs and download it to server.

Answer (score 0):

AuthSub is deprecated. You should be using [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth) and [Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/).

Comment: I do not want to spend time developing new functionality if i dont have to. AuthSub still works.

Comment: What API (and version of the API) are you using? Did your code work at one time and now has stopped working or are you developing something new? What does your code look like?

Comment: I made one component for handling google apps requests. It works with AuthSubSessionToken which is different for each scope. For my new app/web i need just that token for google docs. Code is OOP. Seems that i cant paste it here... So i've added one function on the original Q.